# Correct way to execute aws cli commands from on premise production server, with configured aws vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-vpn, on-premises-instances

I have a situation where it is required us to trigger lambda functions from my production windows server, which is currently running on our, on premise/corporate network.
**note: we have VPN connection established between our corporate data centers and aws VPCs

One way I understand how I can achieve is:
#1 Install AWS Cli on my production server which is running on my corporate data center
#2 Generate secret key and access key from aws, with limited privileges (invoke lambda only)
#3 Configure aws profile on my production instance using these credentials
#4 Execute invoke lambda command using this profile

My Question is: Is this that, is this the best approach to achieve this or is there better solution than this ?

Any tip here would be helpful. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider other options:

- [IAM Roles Anywhere](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/extend-aws-iam-roles-to-workloads-outside-of-aws-with-iam-roles-anywhere/) for step **#2** to generate temporary credentials and eliminate the need to manage permanent ones.
- [Lambda function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) for step **#4** to eliminate the need to install the AWS CLI tool and its dependencies on your server (**#1**).